# How to patch ViewSet.filterset_class to return None?

Tags: django, mocking, pytest

I have this test

```
    @mock.patch("app.views.MyViewSet.filterset_class", return_value=None)
    def test_filter_chat_request_management_status(self, mock_filterset_class):
        query_parameter = "status=accepted"
        response = self.client.get(URL + "?" + query_parameter)
        assert 1 == 1
```

With filterset_class, query_parameter variable does change the behaviour of the MyViewSet (**which I do not want**), therefore it changes the response.

That is why I used @mock.patch to disable filterset class so it does not influence for the response.

However,  when I debug my test (in local test_filter_chat_request_management_status scope), MyViewSet.filterset_class **does not return None as I expect**, **but returns magic mock object instead**.

```
>>> print(MyViewSet.filterset_class)
<MagicMock name='filterset_class' id='4894544640'>
```

Therefore, in rest_framework.backends.py, in class DjangoFilterBackend, in get_filterset_class() method, while executing filterset_class = getattr(view, "filterset_class", None) line of code, filterset_class variable contains <MagicMock name='filterset_class' id='4894544640'> object instean of None.

**How can I force MyViewSet.filterset_class return None?**

Comment: well you patched it with a method that returns `None`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@mock.patch("app.views.MyViewSet.filterset_class", new_callable=mock.PropertyMock)
def test_filter_chat_request_management_status(self, mock_filterset_class):
    mock_filterset_class.return_value = None
    query_parameter = "status=accepted"
    response = self.client.get(URL + "?" + query_parameter)
    assert 1 == 1
```